# Confusion with exact sequences

Tags: group-theory

Consider the sequence:

$$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb{C}\xrightarrow{g}\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow 0$$

Now this sequence is exact in the sense that $\text{Im}\space f=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\text{ker} \space g= \mathbb{Z}$ and thus they are equal and by the definition of exact sequences, this sequence is exact. However I kind of had to guess that $\text{ker}\space g= \mathbb{Z}$ just so the condition holds, and I am not quite sure why the $\text{ker}\space g$ is equal to $\mathbb{Z},$ because from my understanding of kernel, it is all the set of elements of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $g(c\in \mathbb{C})=\text{id}_{\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}}.$ But I do not see why the set of integers if the kernel for the homomorphism $g$?

Could anyone please explain why this is the case?

Edited: $f$ is the inclusion map taking some $z\in \mathbb{Z}$ to itself $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $g$ is the map taking some $c\in \mathbb{C}$ to $e^{2\pi i c} \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$

Comment: What are $f$ and $g$ in your question? I think they need to be specified.

Comment: If $g$ is the exponential map, its kernel is $2\pi i\Bbb Z$ which is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$ as a group.

Comment: If, on the other hand, $g(z)=e^{2\pi iz}$, then its kernel is literally $\mathbb Z$, not just up to isomorphism.  But the same holds if $g(z)=e^{-2\pi iz}$.

Comment: @Andreas Blass This is now my reasoning for why kernel of $g$ is infact the whole $\mathbb{Z}$. 
Reasoning: With the defined function of $g,$ since the identity can no longer be $0$, it is now $1$, and the only value of the function $g$ where it takes the value $1$ is if all the values in $\mathbb{C}$ is infact $\mathbb{Z}$ simple because of the exponential function, the multiples of $2\pi$ continuously gives the value of $1$. is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from my understanding of kernel, it is all the set of elements of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $g(c\in \mathbb{C})=\text{id}_{\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}}.$

Correct. What is $\text{id}_{\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}}$? (What's the group structure on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$?)

> $g$ is the map taking some $c\in\mathbb{C}$ to $e^{2\pi i c} \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$

When is $e^{2\pi i c}$ equal to the identity you've just found above?

Comment: I have made my reasoning in the above comments, I would appreciate if you can check if its correct. Thank You.

Comment: I don't think your reasoning above makes much sense. *Why* is the identity 1? Saying "the identity can no longer be 0" is not enough.

Comment: @because the image of $g$, excludes ${0}$, so we cannot take 0 in to consideration.

Comment: I agree with you that the identity can obviously no longer be 0. But why is it 1, and not e.g. pi, or 25, or sqrt(2)?

Comment: I guess because the binary operation defined is multiplication? Hmm I just automatically thought it was 1, now that seems to be a good question. Why is it 1? Can you help me understand why it it the case?

Comment: Correct, the operation defined *is* supposed to be multiplication. (They haven't said that, but you're supposed to know that that's implicitly what they meant.) Can you prove that the identity is 1 from here?

Comment: Then its simply $ e^{2\pi i c} * i = e^{2\pi i c}$ which implies $i =1.$

Comment: Yes. More generally, for *any* $x\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, we have that $xa = x$ implies $a = 1$. So now you know what the identity is - it's 1. So you can solve the equation $e^{2\pi i c} = 1$ for $c\in \mathbb{C}$.